# Can I use the microchip of Arduino Uno as a standalone microcontroller

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I want use the `ATmega328P` chip of the `Arduino Uno` board as a **standalone** device.

- Is that possible?
- Which pins are which on the Arduino board and the `ATmega328P`?
- Do I need any external components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert Arduino to an ATmega328P-based project?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80049/how-do-i-convert-arduino-to-an-atmega328p-based-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. To use the ATmega328P to "emulate" an Arduino Uno board (without the USB part) you just need 3 ou 4 additional components: the oscillator, two capacitors and a resistor. Please take a look at: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoToBreadboard for a schematic/breadboard.
The Atmega328P features itself the memory, cpu and flash so those components are already inside the chip. You can find the relation of the pins in this image: [image: Pin matching]

Comment: you might also consider running it at 8Mhz w/o an xtal if you want simplicity, but a nano or pro micro would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [UNO's schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf). You can use this as a starting position. You can leave out the things you don't need. You might for example have no need for a voltage regulator on your board.

You may also have a look at the [schematic of the Pro Mini](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino-Pro-Mini-schematic.pdf), which are a lot more bare-bones.